# Print page once the page is completely loaded

Tags: javascript, html, printing

H! I'm trying to print the page from `Javascript`. But In the print preview, it always shows the incomplete page or gaps in the page.

How can I print the page once the HTML in page is completely loaded?

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
var printText = html.innerHTML;
function PrintDiv(data) {
    var mywindow = window.open();
    var is_chrome = Boolean(mywindow.chrome);
    mywindow.document.write(data);
if (is_chrome) {
    setTimeout(function() { // wait until all resources loaded
        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.print(); // change window to winPrint
        mywindow.close(); // change window to winPrint
    }, 1000);
} else {
        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
}
    return true;
}

$(document).load(function() {
    PrintDiv(printText);
});
```

Comment: Is the reason why you're seeing "incomplete page or gaps" because of the stylesheets that are applied to the page when you're trying to print it? https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-4/#mf-display-quality

Comment: hi @goto1, I don't think so. I can see the styles applied in the preview. But I can see some content missing. Like paragraphs or images.

Comment: Does the page also load external scripts and is there also other 
embedded javascript code you haven't posted yet?

Comment: Do you inject the posted code (e.g. as content script) or do you have full control of the complete page. In the latter case it would help if you could share the complete HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is generally caused by a problem that some content of the webpage is loaded via AJAX POST and your printing being executed before the POST requests are answered. To handle this, you will need to issue the printing after all your content is loaded, which is way after the page load event happened. So, you will need to convert your AJAX requests into [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and call the [.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method on them to guarantee that print occurs at the right place at the right time. Example:

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```